# Sci-fi/Fantasy Book, woman fighter refugee from another planet gets job as secretary/assistant

Tags: story-identification, books

So what I remember from the book (possibly short story) is that two planets were at war, one lost and all the fighters get killed(or sent to prison?) and the rest get to go to the winning planet as refugees, if they pass the "I'm not a fighter check". The technology is very advanced.

A *really* good mental fighter woman gets blockers in her mind to pose as a regular person so she doesn't get killed/sent to prison. She gets an apartment of some sort on the new planet she's on, and gets to work as a secretary/assistant for a big company owned/lead by a man who's also a really good mental fighter. They then meet in a computer thing/dream/mental world of some sort and he tries to find out who she is.
The fight is mental in some way. They end up falling in love

I read it less than 5 years ago and the story was written less than 20 years ago, it was in English and I thought it was a story by Ilona Andrews, someone they know/have collaborated with, or someone with that style. It's either ya or above.

I remember some other things that might be from this story, but not for sure.
There were other secretaries, and they didn't like the main character. They thought she dressed poorly. Either the main character or one of the secretaries has red hair.
She was very good at her new job, but also super overqualified, which she didn't want anyone to find out.
In her spare time she might have been reading books, but again, I'm not sure if that's from this story or not.

Comment: Hi there! Could you maybe [edit] in some other details such as when you read that, if it was in English, translated or not, what the cover looked like etc? Stuff like this, to increase the chances of a successful identification. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I forgot the name but remember the author check out Ilona Andrew's books. You may have to scroll down a bit into the short story area but there's an accompanying book as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Silver Shark](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005N9FPOO)* by Ilona Andrews:

> Family is everything. Talent is power. And revenge is sweet.
>   In a distant, future world Kinsmen--small powerful groups of genetically and technologically advanced families--control vast financial empires. They are their own country, their own rulers, and their only limits are other Kinsmen. The struggle for power is a bloody, full-contact sport: in business, on the battlefield...and sometimes in the bedroom. 
>   Claire Shannon is a killer...and her weapon is her mind.
>   Born on a planet torn by war for over 300 years, Claire is a soldier: a psycher, with the ability to read, control, and destroy the minds of enemy psychers and to infiltrate the biological network where they battle to death.
>   When Claire's faction loses the war, she barely escapes extermination from both sides, as her talent brands her as too dangerous to society. By so-deeply burying her ability that she avoids detection, Claire is instead deported to Rada as a refugee, where she must find work to remain. She finds a job as personal assistant to Venturo Escana, a premiere kinsman; one of Rada's most wealthy entrepreneurs--and most powerful psychers.
>
> She thought she had left war behind, but now she must  hide her skills and her growing feelings from Venturo...and this battle might just cost her everything...

- Claire is a psycher (mental warrior)
- Her side loses
- She hides her abilities so she can be exiled to another planet rather than killed
- She becomes the personal assistant for a powerful psycher and head of a family / CEO of a security business on the new planet
- She changes her hair color in the story

Comment: This is it, thanks! Don't know how I missed it, completely mistook that series for another one (facepalm).....
Thanks again!